# Scispacy for biomedical named entitiy recognition(NER)

Tags: python, nlp, bioinformatics, named-entity-recognition

**How to label entities using scispacy?**

When I tried to perform NER using `scispacy`, it identified the biomedical entities by labeling them as `Entity` but failed to label them as gene/protein, etc.. So how do I do that using `scispacy`? Or is `scispacy` not capable of labeling data? The image is attached for reference:
[jupyter notebook snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QySa5.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The models `en_core_sci_sm`, `en_core_sci_md` and `en_core_sci_lg` do not name their entities. If you want labeled entities use the models

- en_ner_craft_md
- en_ner_jnlpba_md
- en_ner_bc5cdr_md
- en_ner_bionlp13cg_md

each of which has its own type of entities see:-

https://allenai.github.io/scispacy/

for more information

Comment: Note of caution, these models do label the same entity differently. Eg. "secukinumab" can  get labeled as 'Gene or Gene Product', 'Protein', or 'Simple Chemical' depending on which model one uses. 
Or for new entities, might not get detected at all. Eg. newly approved/discovered drugs.

Answer (score 1):

## Install required Modules

```
!pip install spacy
# !pip install https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ai2-s2-scispacy/releases/v0.5.1/en_ner_bionlp13cg_md-0.5.1.tar.gz
# !pip install scispacy
```

## Load Packages

```
import scispacy, spacy
sci_nlp = spacy.load("en_ner_bionlp13cg_md")
```

## components of the NLP Object

```
sci_nlp.component_names
```

## Explore entities

```
c= 0 
for i in sci_nlp.get_pipe('ner').labels:
    c=c+1
    print(c,"<==>",i)
# output
1 <==> AMINO_ACID
2 <==> ANATOMICAL_SYSTEM
3 <==> CANCER
4 <==> CELL
5 <==> CELLULAR_COMPONENT
6 <==> DEVELOPING_ANATOMICAL_STRUCTURE
7 <==> GENE_OR_GENE_PRODUCT
8 <==> IMMATERIAL_ANATOMICAL_ENTITY
9 <==> MULTI_TISSUE_STRUCTURE
10 <==> ORGAN
11 <==> ORGANISM
12 <==> ORGANISM_SUBDIVISION
13 <==> ORGANISM_SUBSTANCE
14 <==> PATHOLOGICAL_FORMATION
15 <==> SIMPLE_CHEMICAL
16 <==> TISSUE


x = "Med7 — An information extraction model for clinical natural language processing. More information about the model development can be found in recent pre-print: Med7: a transferable clinical natural language processing model for electronic health records."

docx = sci_nlp(x)
for ent in docx.ents:
    print(ent.text,ent.label_)
#output
Med7 GENE_OR_GENE_PRODUCT
Med7 GENE_OR_GENE_PRODUCT
```

## visulaize

```
from spacy import displacy
displacy.render(docx,style='ent',jupyter=True)

#output
Med7 GENE_OR_GENE_PRODUCT — An information extraction model for clinical natural language processing. More information about the model development can be found in recent pre-print: Med7 GENE_OR_GENE_PRODUCT : a transferable clinical natural language processing model for electronic health records.
```

Comment: Very minor note: If this is vanilla Jupyter, you should be suggesting use the magic command `%pip install spacy` and not the exclamation point when installing from inside the notebook. The modern magic command `%pip install` was added to insure installations occur in the correct environment backing the kernel that underlies the notebook. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the modern magic commands. The exclamation point doesn't handle the environment and can lead to issues, hence the need ...

Comment: <continued> to add the magic commands to make it much more robust these days. For those using Anaconda/conda/mamba, there is a related `%conda install`. For more about the shortcoming of the exclamation point for this particular task see the first sentence [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez).

Answer (score 1):

The model used here might not be the spaCy's Named Entity Recognition Model. So, in order to get the labels of the entities, use any of the following NER models depending on the types of entity labels you want.

Image containing all NER Models[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4tNQ.jpg)

- For gene label, **en_ner_bionlp13cg_md** can be used.
- For protein label, **en_ner_jnlpba_md** can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the label by 'GENE_OR_GENE_PRODUCT' to get all gene names.

```
import spacy
import scispacy
import en_ner_bionlp13cg_md

document = "We aimed to prospectively compare the risk of early progression according to circulating ESR1 mutations, CA-15.3, and circulating cell-free DNA in MBC patients treated with a first-line aromatase inhibitor (AI)"

nlp = spacy.load("en_ner_bionlp13cg_md")
for X in nlp(document).ents:
    if X.label_=='GENE_OR_GENE_PRODUCT':
        print(X.text)
```